# Is there a way to merge two strings or variables to access another variable in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, concatenation

I have a program that is trying to list my classes for school (in a UITableView), along with the homework for each class. I have variables to track homework for each class as lists (i.e "Englishhw", "Mathhw", etc.), and I want to make it so that in my function, I can take the name of the class, and add "hw" to find the associated variable list. I have all of my homework lists for each class in one View Controller, and based on what the person selected (with the didSelectRowAt function, I can find that), I would show different table view contents for the homework in that class (instead of making a separate view controller for each subject). Here is my code:

```swift
    @IBOutlet var className: UILabel!
    var classList = ["Language", "Math", "English"]
    var Languagehw = ["hi", "bye", "New Assignment . . .", "Remove Assignment . . ."]
    var Mathhw = ["him", "bye", "New Assignment . . .", "Remove Assignment . . ."]
    var Englishhw = ["hime", "bye", "New Assignment . . .", "Remove Assignment . . ."]



   func addAssignment(subject: String) {
        for subject in classList {
            if className.text! == subject { 
                 // subject + hw to find associated variable (ex. subject = English, subject + hw => Englishhw, which is one of my homework lists
            }
            else {}
        }
    }
```

In this code, I'm making a function that checks if the className is equal to a subject in classList (a list with all of the classes) through a for loop and then trying to find the related list by adding the subject + hw. For example, if I wanted to find my "Englishhw" list, I could use the function to find if the class they selected was "English", and then add "hw" at the end to find the list correctly. However, I don't know if there is a way to concatenate strings (in this case, English and hw) to find a variable. Is there actually concatenate strings into variables?

Comment: I haven't been learning Swift for too long, so I'm not sure what you mean... what do you mean by using objects, not arrays?

Comment: Variable names are fictitious concept invented solely for developer convenience. They don't actually exist within the program after compilation. It looks like you're looking for a [`Dictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary).

Comment: @Swaraag the duplicate link might answer your particular question, however, as others have said, you are looking at the problem from the wrong angle.

Comment: @Cristik I made it a dictionary and had the key be the class and the values being the homework in a list. When making the textlabel the indexPath.row, it gives me a "Fatal error: Index out of range" error. `cell.textLabel?.text = subjecthw["spanhw"]?[indexPath.row]`. 
Even when I make a variable for that specific key and value, it gives me the same error. 
`var spanhw = subjecthw["spanhw"]` 
`cell.textLabel?.text = spanhw?[indexPath.row]`

Comment: You’re trying to access an index larger than the number of elements in the array. For example, if the array has 2 elements and you’re tying to access the item at index 5

Comment: `"spanhw": ["hi", "bye", "New Assignment . . .", "Remove Assignment . . ."]` is the spanhw part of my dictionary. It has 4 values, but I made it ` return 10` in numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: Oh just realized what you're saying. That makes a lot more sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Forget concatenation; it's irrelevant.

What you need to know is that Swift has no introspection. There is no way to get from the *string* "Language" to the value of the *variable* `Language` (or `Languagehw` or anything else); that is a metaphysical impossibility.

You need to rethink your entire architecture (which is pretty bad already: you should be using objects, not arrays). If you need to access a particular value by way of a string, that would be a dictionary with string keys.

Comment: This is more of a comment. If I were OP, I wouldn't know where to go from here.

Comment: @Alexander Gosh, I think I've answered the question; what the OP wants to do (access the value of the variable `Languagehw` by forming the string `"Languagehw"`) is impossible. Done.

Comment: To add to @Alexander's comment, this question was asked a lot of times before, let's give the man the duplicate reference, and guide him in the comments if we want to make the world a better place

Comment: "You can't do that" without a suggestion of "but you can try this instead" has pretty minuscule utility.

Comment: I totally agree about the duplicate. The problem is that the question was wrongly closed as a duplicate of questions about string concatenation. I reopened it _exactly_ so that we could replace that with a duplicate about string access to variables.

Comment: The discussion here is about the answer, not the question, if you were sure the question was a duplicate, albeit of a different one, then the best course of actions would've been to just reopen it and leave a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Inside your for loop, you can write it as-

```
if className.text! == subject + "hw" { 
      // here subject + "hw" is Englishhw now.
}
```

We can easily concate string as-
after the given string `mystring + "hw"`
before given string `"hw" + mystring`

Comment: How would you be able to access that string then? Say I wanted to add a new assignment to that specific Englishhw list in this function, how could I do that?